# WPF UI Thread blocked with large collection

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have a WPF application built using MVVM; one of the Views contains a collection of models that can be between 200-500 in length, each of the models are mapped to a RepositoryViewModel and bound to the 'Repository.xaml' view in a stack panel.

The top level View (Main.xaml) is as follows:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type home:RepositoryViewModel}">
        <vw:Repository />
    </DataTemplate>
<Window.Resources>
<ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Margin="5 40 5 5">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True">
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Repositories}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        </ItemsControl>
    </StackPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Repository.xaml UserControl is as follows:

```
<Grid Margin="5" Visibility="{Binding Model.Visibility}" >
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="WrapPanelGroup" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <StackPanel Grid.Column="1">     
        <!--Textbox is used to allow user to select the text. Changing to Label does not help with rendering issues-->       
        <TextBox Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" Text="{Binding Model.Name}" IsReadOnly="True"
                 TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="18" MaxWidth="300" />
        <TextBox Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" Text="{Binding Model.Url}" IsReadOnly="True"
                 TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="8" MaxWidth="300" Foreground="DarkGray" />
    </StackPanel>
    <Button Grid.Column="2" Content="Checkout" Command="{Binding CheckoutCommand}" Visibility="{Binding Model.SingleCheckoutVisible}"/>
    <CheckBox Grid.Column="2" IsChecked="{Binding Model.IsChecked}" Visibility="{Binding Model.BulkCheckoutVisible}"/>
</Grid>
```

The above works perfectly as I require, the issue is the time WPF takes to render the controls- once each of the `RepositoryViewModel`'s are added to the `RepositoryViewModel` `ObservableCollection` the entire UI freezes for 3-5 seconds whilst the controls are rendered.

Whilst trying to isolate the issue I noticed that by removing the textbox's the render time dramatically decreases but removing the binding on the textbox's does not make a noticeable difference. Swapping the textbox's for labels made little difference.

Is the collection size simply to large to expect WPF to handle quickly or am I missing something that is increasing the render time? I did consider having a `SharedSizeGroup` with a MaxWidth may be the culprit but removing did not improve performance.

Thanks.

Comment: Update: the main culprit increasing render time was because I had a dynamic height & width on each user control within the WrapPanel, setting a fixed height/width dramatically increased render time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look into adding virtualization to your ItemsControl. This way it only renders the items in view rather than all of them.

```
<ItemsControl VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"
              ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <VirtualizingStackPanel />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```

I believe you'd also need to remove the ItemsControl from the StackPanel and ScrollViewer, as they'll give the ItemsControl infinite space to render, and render the virtualization useless.

I see you're using a WrapPanel for your ItemsPanelTemplate, so you may need to roll your own virtualized panel, or check out some [other](http://www.telerik.com/products/wpf/virtualizingwrappanel.aspx) [controls](https://virtualwrappanel.codeplex.com/) (haven't used these myself).

Comment: Also don't forget to look at the control at run-time with the WPF tree visualizer to confirm that virtualization is in fact working correctly, it has a nasty habit of breaking all too easily.

Comment: Thanks, I will do some research on virtualization. I forgot to mention there is also a search that sets the value of `Model.Visibility` (used in Repository.xaml) to visible or collapsed but I assume that is supported in virtualization?

Comment: Meaning you basically want certain items filtered out of view based on different conditions? Look into binding your ItemsControl to a CollectionViewSource. This can handle all the different ways you want to present your view, including sorting and filtering.